# Tensor product of generator of SU(n)

Tags: lie-groups, qa.quantum-algebra, matrix-analysis, quantum-mechanics

I'm doing research in quantum mechanics and got some trouble. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Let $\{\lambda_j\}$ be the set of generator of $SU(n)$. Consider the operator:
$K=\sum_j \lambda_j\otimes\lambda_j$.

I would like to know the eigenvalues and if possible the eigenvectors of the operator $K$. For $SU(2)$ and $SU(3)$ it is fairly easy because i know $\lambda_j$, but the general case is what I am interested in. I have been googling around but I don't even know what people call $K$. Any keyword is also appreciated.

Thanks,

Minh

PS: Useful link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gell-Mann_matrices. In the link there are matrices that are generators of $SU(3)$. In that case I was able to find the eigenvalues of $K$ which are $4/3$ and $-8/3$. I would like to do the same for higher dimension.

Comment: Do you mean the groups or algebras? We usually write in capitol letters for the groups and small for the Lie algebras. What do you mean by generators?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I guess I mean group. By generators i mean the generators of the group. For example for SU(2) they are the Pauli matrices. I guess there is nothing about Lie algebra then. Am I making any sense?

Comment: I suspect you mean the Casimir element (operator) (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casimir_element for a start) for the unitary group. If so, just google it.

Comment: Hi Sasha. Thanks for your comment. In Casimir element the product is the matrix multiplication while here I am interested in the tensor product. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Minh Tran, I assume that $K$ is some linear operator coming from some representation $V$ of $SU(n)$. More specifically, I'm guessing that $V$ is a tensor product of certain representations of $SU(n)$. If this is true, it might help if you told us what $V$ was.

Comment: Hi Peter. Unfortunately it is not the case. While calculating some expectation values, the operator $A$ appears directly into my calculation. To minimize the expectation value, i'm trying to find the eigenvalues of the operator $K$.

Comment: I just added some information that might be useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

There are several points (often confused!) to be cleared up here:

Those "generators" (as in the Gell-Mann Wiki article) are "infinitesimal generators", which means that they are a basis for the Lie *algebra*.

Further, the convention with the specific Gell-Mann generators makes them an *orthonormal* basis with respect to the natural inner product on the Lie algebra... which is invariant under the Adjoint action of the Lie group, and is secretly the "Killing form" (or its negative, etc).

Given that, as @SashaAnan'in speculated, you have written the *Casimir* operator.

Note that the Casimir operator is *not* expressed via "matrix multiplication", but by multiplication in the "universal enveloping algebra". The latter is indeed a quotient of the universal associative algebra, often called the "tensor algebra" (although that is more a construction than a description of the characterizing features of that algebra), and the expression of the Casimir operator as a tensor is an expression of a representative in that "covering" algebra.

So, apart from additional clarifications and potential misunderstandings, you have exactly written the Casimir operator.

On any irreducible representation of the Lie group (and/or Lie algebra) Casimir acts by a scalar, by some form of Schur's lemma, since the Casimir operator commutes with the action of the group.

One way to compute the eigenvalues of Casimir on irreducible is to use the fact that an irreducible of a compact Lie group such as $SU(n)$ has a unique highest-weight vector. Then standard computations inside the universal enveloping algebra (not matrices!) produce the eigenvalues in terms of that highest weight, without too much difficulty.

(The above remarks were partly meant to include useful keywords...)